# Do we know what the Joker's third origin story would have been?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight, the-joker

In *The Dark Knight*, the Joker is about to tell a third origin story but gets interrupted by Batman.

> Joker: Speaking of which, you know how I got these scars?
>
> Batman: No, but I know how you got these.
>
> *Violence ensues*

Has the contents of his third story been revealed in anyway?

Comment: That would be totally missing the point, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ah... Witty repartee. Batman's strong suit.

Comment: @buzz what point? How would it be missed?

Comment: @1252748: Batman specifically ignored Joker's attempt at telling his origin story, because it's irrelevant (lies and deceit) and and attempt at manipulation in the midst of combat. OP still trying to figure out what Joker would have said completely misses the point that the story would have been random bullshit that doesn't matter. (Note: this is from an in-universe point of view. Of course WE are interested in the character exposition (even if it is a lie), rather than the necessity of hearing a fabricated story.)

Answer (score 9):

After having heard two separate backstories (each of which is notably applicable to the person who he tells the story to); we can assume that the Joker's origin stories are lies; intended to both manipulate, distract, and add to the perception of his unhinged persona.

During Joker's third (attempt at a) story, Batman completely ignores the Joker's attempt at starting a conversation, and continues with the fight that is occurring.
If I had to put Batman's reaction into words: Quit your bullshit.

We don't know for sure what the Joker would have said. But given what we know of the other origin stories; the third story would be one that is very applicable to Batman.
E.g. about how the scars are Joker's punishment for being a dictatorial bully  (which is a not-so-hidden analogy for suggesting that Batman will at some point be punished for his deeds).